# PHP MySQL Query to Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I hope you can help me. I need help to translate a line of code made in PHP to CodeIgniter, it is as follows:

```
$rs = sqlQuery("select concat(t.tbl_row,'_',t.tbl_col) as pos, t.tbl_id, t.sub_id, s.sub_name from redips_timetable t, redips_subject s where t.sub_id = s.sub_id", 0);
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/)  - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('CONCAT(t.tbl_row, " ", t.tbl_col) as pos, t.tbl_id, t.tbl_sub_id, s.sub_name', false);
$this->db->join('redips_timetable AS t', 't.sub_id = s.sub_id');
return $this->db->get('redips_subject AS s')->result();
```

It's important to note the second param `false` passed to `select()`, a failure to include this will have CI attempting to escape your concat.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, implement the code and I get the following error:                                                            PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /home/public_html/demo/application/views/dmeo.php on line 12

Comment: You cannot use a codeigniter model without being iin object context. Don't try to put this in a view, put it in a model and call it from a controller.